# Opencv (JavaScript) Mat from Array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, opencv, mat

I'm trying to create a mat from an 2d array using the `cv.matFromArray(rows, cols, type, array);` method.

It works with really small arrays like this:

```
  let mat = cv.matFromArray(2, 2, cv.CV_8UC1, [255, 255, 128, 128]);
  return mat; // works
```

But when i basically do the same thing with my image array (1024x1024px, values range from 20 to 230) it just fills every Mat value to 0

```
const mat = cv.matFromArray(img_array.length, img_array[0].length, cv.CV_8UC1, img_array);
return mat; // every value is 0
```

Why is that?

Comment: Could you add the `img_array` to the question?

Comment: no, its an 1024x1024 array with values ranging from 20-255

Comment: i'm guessing that i have to convert my 2d array to 1d in oder to work.

Comment: I don't see documentation for the usage you're describing. I found this which shows the 4th argument being a scalar, not an array: https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/d06/tutorial_js_basic_ops.html And it looks like a scalar is an array of R, G, B, A: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/df1/tutorial_js_some_data_structures.html

Comment: i found the solution myself. if you're still curious about `MatFromArray` "documentation";

https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/d06/tutorial_js_basic_ops.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I converted the 2d array to 1d like this:

```
[].concat(...img_array);
```

and its working now:

```
img_array; // 1024x1024px 2d array

const mat = cv.matFromArray(img_array.length, img_array[0].length, cv.CV_8UC1, [].concat(...img_array));
return mat;
```